# Passing Admin Credentials Works in Windows PowerShell ISE but not Running PowerShell At CMD

Tags: powershell-4.0

I believe the password is not being passed into the SCHTASKS command via Get-Credentials cmdlet for it's blank when writing to host before executing the command.

I'm logged in as my non-DomainAdminUser account and when Get-Credentials ask me to authenticate - I enter my DomainAdminUser account which populates and executes the SCHTASKS correctly using the ISE for PowerShell.

Why would it fail to authenticate - populate the password after /P when running PowerShell at the console.

C:\Users\NOTAdmin>powershell
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\Users\NOTdomainAdmin> C:\Scripts\ohniceone.ps1
Please provide your credentials so the script can continue.
Ok
SCHTASKS /Query /FO csv /v /s computer /U OurDomain\DomainAdminUser /P  | ConvertFrom-Csv
ERROR: Access is denied.

Comment: when I execute Get-Content $profile in ISE it returns nothing without an error.  when I run it within the PSConsole it returns ----PS C:\Users\NOTAdmin> get-content $profile
get-content : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\NOTAdmin\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1' because it does not exist.

Comment: this shows me the Alternate Admin account password in ISE but not when I run it from the console - why would it work only in ISE where I can see the password. NOTE it will show me my currently logged in password text in both ISE and PSConsole - but not alternate account ----> https://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/get-credential/

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue. We solved it by having the scheduled task run as the `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` account. Off course you'll need to verify the permissions, but normally it will run as the logged on user.